# Change date on an OpenVZ VPS

Tags: debian, date, time, vps, openvz

I have a cheap OpenVZ VPS, and I noticed the time is a lot wrong.

Each time I try:

```
ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

it silently returns as if it was successful, but nothing changes.

When I do:

```
date -s 11:11
```

it says `date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted`.

**Is there a trick to be able to modify date on an OpenVZ VPS?**

Note: I have done `service ntpd stop`, but it's already not running.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it may be late to post here:
I ended up here because I had the same problem. (Actually one cronjob installed automatically was throwing a daily error-eMail when calling ntpdate).

As described on other postings: in openVZ a node (your VPS) can not set it's own time. The time is derived from the common terminal for ALL vps using the kernel. The time update should be done for you by the hostsystem. IF you are running he VPS you can enable the time/date call for a node; HOWEVER, a call from one node would change the time for all others ... perhaps a bad idea.

For my problem ... I simply removed the ntpdate call from the cronjob ... (the server time is correct and apparently maintained by my host ...)